# Webpack 4 optimize-minimize ignored with mode=development

Tags: webpack

I used to use Webpack 3 where I had 3 different builds:

1. A full debug build where the code is unminified and is similiar to the mode=development.
2. A test build where it is similar to mode=development but it uses minified code for smaller package size.
3. A prod build which is basically the same as mode=production and the -p flag.

What I a having trouble is replicating my 'test' build where I had a development version of my bundle (mainly to keep react development tools) but had a bundle size that was nearly close to my production build.

Here is what I have:

```
NODE_ENV='development' webpack --optimize-minimize --mode=development
```

This no longer works as the optimize-minimize flag is being ignored so my bundle is pretty big.

Answer (score 2):

Use the webpack.config.js file, and ensure minimize is set to true within optimization.

```
optimization: {
        minimize: true,
        minimizer: [new TerserPlugin({
            terserOptions: {
              mangle: true, // Note `mangle.properties` is `false` by default.
            },
        })],
},
```

Comment: I have `mode:production` and `optimization.minimize:false` but regardless Webpack still minimizes. Any idea?